# Possible to force order of TX locks in ORA?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, deadlock

While analyzing a deadlock caused by two concurrent `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statements I found following interesting article: https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/select-for-update-in-what-order-are-the-rows-locked/

The article proofs that Oracle behaves differently to MySQL & PostgreSQL by performing row (TX) locks in the order rows are accessed and not in the order they are fetched (i.e. not in the order specified by `ORDER BY`).

In my scenario query A specified the PK of the table in the Where-clause and query B only an indexed FK. Both access more than 500 rows. I understand that if access is performed via the indexed FK we easily get another order of TX locks compared to accessing via the PK, therefor possibly causing a deadlock.

If both queries use only the PK, is the order of TX locks deterministic? I.e. can I be sure that no deadlocks are possible for two `SELECT FOR UPDATE` queries with large `IN` conditions for the PK? The PK-Column is indexed, never changes and monotonically increasing.

I know that one usually would make use of a `NOWAIT` clause in such cases, but am still interested whether the problem can be solved without such or not. Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about blocks or deadlocks ? deadlocks usually is released by oracle with this error  `ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource` and you can get the result which session blocking the other in the trace file (or alert.log)

Comment: Deadlock - I also have the according trace file at hand and can offer parts of it, if you're interested. Simplification: What happens is that the first query wants to lock rows in e.g. the order 1-2-3-4-5 and the second query in order 4-3-5-2-1. The attached link describes how you can reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: well if you specified order by desc for both query the deadlock (technically ) shouldnt occur. or your mentioning about another problem

Comment: That was also my assumption. What you mention is true for MySQL and PostgreSQL, but not Oracle. To quote from the article of the original post: 
"I would have suggested that the rows are locked as the rows are read from the table blocks, and not after the ORDER BY clause alters the order of the rows. Why? Oracle Database is fundamentally lazy, or put another way, fundamentally efficient – in general it does not perform unnecessary work. Locking the rows after applying the ORDER BY clause would require a second
visit to the table blocks.."

Comment: The key here is that the two queries do not access the table via the same index, therefore having different access plans. With different access plans we also receive different orders of row locks. 
My open question is if a given access plan guarantees a deterministic order of row access (i.e. if the same query will lock the same rows always in the same order)

Comment: Would having a cursor to simply fetch the rows in a given order without a `FOR UPDATE`, then use the `ROWID` of the returned rows on a second inner cursor for locking that row help? Means two visits to the row/block.

Comment: @TenG your talking about optimistic blocking and you check with rowscn

Comment: @TenG Thanks, that's indeed a possible solution. I'm still wondering if there is a way of handling this with a single table access. The application showing this behaviour performs a lot of batch processing where several 1000 records may be locked.